# jquery doesn't focus the selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that:

1. check the relevant checkbox if the user input a value in a text input
2. verify if user input is duplicated, alert and focus the text input where user inserted the wrong value

This is my code:

```
$('.seq').blur(function(){

    if($(this).val()!=''){
        $(this).closest(".percheckbox").find("input:checkbox:first").prop("checked", true);
        if ($('.seq').not(this).val() == $(this).val()) {
            alert('Duplicated entry. Change it please.');
            console.log($(this).attr('name'));
            $(this).focus();
        }
    }else if ($(this).val()=='') {
        $(this).closest(".percheckbox").find("input:checkbox:first").prop("checked", false); 
    }
});
```

The only point that is not working is `$(this).focus();` even if console.log shows that 'this' is the right element.

EDIT: this is the html:

```
<div class="sez-form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Messaggi inclusi</legend>

    <?php $i = 0; foreach($msgs as $msg) { ?>

        <div class="percheckbox">
            <input class="checkseq" type="checkbox" name="messaggio[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $msg['id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $msg['nome']; ?>
            <br>
            <label>Ordine: </label><input class="seq" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text" name="ordine[<?php echo $i; ?>]">
        </div>
    <?php $i += 1; } ?> 
    <br style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

Sorry for the wrong code formatting but I still have some problems with stackoverlow text editing.

Comment: To have proper formatting after a list, have a line between the list and the code. Event an hmtl comment will work. Also it is very bad practice to alert and focus in a blur event. You need to use a timeout to handle that in all browsers

Comment: Thanks for both advices. Alert will be replaced by another notification (in the DOM itself). Anyway I'll check the use of the timeout function in this case!

Comment: You should definitely cache `$(this)`.

Comment: What do you mean @dl3? Why should I chache $(this)?

Comment: can we see the `html`?

Comment: Added in my original question. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work actually, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pbx2yof/

Check if none of your other code interfers with it. I'd remove everything else and check if it works, then piece by piece re-add your other code.

Stackoverflow doesn't let me answer without code so here is the html code I used (JS Code is unchanged)

```
<div class="sez-form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Messaggi inclusi</legend>

        <div class="percheckbox">
            <input class="checkseq" type="checkbox" name="messaggio0" value="0"/>
            0
            <br>
           <label>Ordine: </label>
           <input class="seq" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text" name="ordine0"/>
        </div>

        <div class="percheckbox">
            <input class="checkseq" type="checkbox" name="messaggio1" value="1"/>
            1
            <br>
           <label>Ordine: </label>
           <input class="seq" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text" name="ordine1"/>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <br style="clear: both;">
</div>
```